# Solving equations which includes factorials

Tags: permutations, factorial

I tried solve this question:

If $x$ things can be arranged in $m$ ways, $x-2$ things can be arranged in $n$ ways and $x-6$ things can be arranged in $p$ ways and $m = 30np$, then find $x$.

$m = 30np$
$\therefore x! = 30(x-2)!(x-6)!$
$\therefore x(x-1)(x-2)! = 30(x-2)!(x-6)!$
$\therefore x(x-1) = 30(x-6)!$

In the last equation, if you use try and error method, then you will find $6$ is answer for $x$...

But is there a way to find $x$ mathematically?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/swbsywhgvt There are other solutions to the equation ... but assuming $x$ is a positive integer ... $x=6$.

Comment: "*but assuming $x$ is a positive integer*"... I think that is more than a safe assumption @DonaldSplutterwit because we are told "*if $x$ things can be arranged in $m$ ways...*"  This sentence makes no reference to the gamma function and when $x$ is not a non-negative integer the phrase no longer makes sense.  What does it mean to arrange $\pi$ number of things?  Before worrying about arranging them, what even could be meant by $\pi$ number of things?

Answer (score 0):

$x(x-1) = 30(x-6)!$ Suppose $x > 6$

$\frac {x(x+1)}{x-6} = \frac {x^2 - 6x + 7x-42 + 42}{x-6} = x + 7 + \frac {42}{x-6} = 30(x-7)!$  Suppose $x > 7$.

$\frac {x(x+1)}{(x-6)(x-7)} = 1 + \frac {14}{x-7} + \frac{42}{(x-6)(x-7)} = 30(x-8)!$

But $1 + \frac {14}{x-7} + \frac{42}{(x-6)(x-7)}\le 1 + 14 + 21 = 36$ so $(x-8)! = 1$.

Or in other words $x \le 9$.

But $x(x+1) = 30(x-6)!$ so $5|x(x+1)$ so $5|x$ or $5|x-1$ so $x = 6$ or $x=5$. $x$ can't be $5$.

or

Basically $x(x-1) \approx x^2$ and $(x-6)! \approx (\frac x2)^{x-6}$ should indicate $x-6 \approx 2$.  Knowing that $30|x(x-1)$ pinpoints it to $x = 6$.